What is different about the 2024 character sheets?
Along with the recently released 2024 Player's Handbook, there are newly drafted pre-printed character sheets.
I’m interested to know what changes are necessitated by the rules update, and which aspects have been added or removed.

The most fundamental difference is that the character sheet is now 2 pages rather than 3.
As a TL;DR none of the changes are necessitated by rules changes from what I can tell (just renaming of some things and reorganizing otherwise). The following sections have been removed:

Personality Traits, Ideals, Bonds, and Flaws section
Fields for Age, Height, Weight, Eyes, Skin, and Hair
Allies and Organization
Additional Features & Traits (although there is much more space for these)
Treasure

As far as I can tell, no full sections have been added but a number of sections have been improved with subsections and fields for better organization and readability.

Now, let's go through each section on the original official 5e sheets one by one
Marketing Image Link to follow along
Page 1
Character Origin Details

Name, class, background, and race have been moved from a full length top bar to the top left
Race is now called Species
A subclass field was added
Alignment has been moved to the background and personality section found on the second page (discussed later)


Level and Experience

The level field is now in it's own area on the top bar rather than being included in the class field
The experience field joins it there


Armor Class and Hit Points

The Armor Class and hit points have been moved from the middle column to the also join the top bar
A Shield checkbox has been added to the Armor Class section
Temporary Hit Points have lost their own section joining the Hit Points section
Initiative and Speed remained in the same spot (discussed later).


Logo

The "Dungeons & Dragons" Logo is moved from the top left to below the top bar
There is no more stylized Dragon


Proficiency Bonus, Ability Bonus, Skills, and Inspiration

These portions of the character sheet remain in the same place but have been reorganized
The primary change is that the saving throws and skills have been moved under their respective ability scores
Proficiency bonus is moved to the top left of this section
Inspiration, now called Heroic Inspiration, is moved to the bottom right of this section


Equipment Proficiencies

This section remains in the same place in the bottom left
Armor, Weapons, and Tools are broken down
Check boxes for Armor types are added
Languages are moved to their own section on the second page (discussed later)


Key Traits

Initiative and speed remain in the topmost bar right of the ability score section
This bar is extended to include size and passive perception
This extension is possible because the Personality Traits, Ideals, Bonds, and Flaws section is completely removed


Weapon and Cantrip Attacks

With the HP section moved, the Weapon and Cantrip Attacks section is moved to take its place
Like the Key Traits section it is extended to fill the space that the Personality Traits, Ideals, Bonds, and Flaws section vacated
A notes section is added


Features and Traits

With the Weapon and Cantrip Attacks section moved, the Features and Traits section is able to take up the real estate in the center of the page
Equipment is moved to page 2 (discussed later) also freeing up more real estate
The Features and Traits section is divided into Class Features, Species Traits, and Feats
There is no longer an Additional Features & Traits field (on page 2 of the old version)


That concludes page 1; page 2 and 3 (character details and spells) of the old character sheets into one page:
Page 2
Granular Appearance Fields

The fields for Age, Height, Weight, Eyes, Skin, and Hair are removed entirely


Appearance

The Character Appearance section, now called Appearance, is moved from the top left to the top right
The new section is considerably smaller than the old version


Backstory and Personality

The Character Backstory is moved from the bottom left to just below Appearance.
It's title is also adjusted to include Personality accounting for the lack of that field on page 1
Alignment is added as a field in this section
The new section is considerably smaller than the old version


Languages

The languages are now in their own section beneath Backstory and Personality


Equipment and Wealth

Equipment and Wealth are moved to the bottom right of page 2 from page 1
Magic Item Attunement fields have been added
Coins is now it's own section and is changed from vertical to horizontal
There is no longer a Treasure section (on page 2 of the old version)


Allies and Organizations

This section is not present on the new sheet


Spellcasting Class and Ability Details

Kernelpanic in the comments provided a clean photograph of page 2 that shows these details are moved to the top left


Spell Slots

These are now organized at the top of the spells section rather than being found in each section of spells


Cantrips and Prepared Spells

Kernelpanic's image shows that Cantrips and Prepared Spells are in the next section taking up most of the page.
This section is no longer organized by spell level
There are fields for Level, Name, Casting Time, Range, and Notes
There are check boxes for Concentration, Ritual, and Required Material (probably to indicate a focus won't work)



https://imgur.com/a/aDAabOV I unfortunately don't own an appropriate scanner for books. The overlayed numbers reference sections of the character creation guide in the new PHB

@KernelPanic Thanks; updated the spells section
